# OData - How to filter on child elements?

Tags: filter, odata

We have an endpoint where the payload looks like this:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost/AbcWebApi/v1.0/-/ABC/AP/$metadata#APDistributionSets/$entity",
  "DistributionSetKey": "CC",
  "Description": "Credit cards",
  "Status": "Active",
  "InactiveDate": null,
  "DateLastMaintained": "2010-08-18T00:00:00Z",
  "CodeType": "Purchase",
  "DistributionMethod": "Manual",
  "DistributionsEntered": 3,
  "Currency": "CAD",
  "DistributionSetDetails": [
    {
      "DistributionSet": "CC",
      "LineNumber": 1,
      "DistributionCode": "VISA",
      "Description": "VISA card",
      "GLAccount": "1022",
      "Discountable": "Yes",
      "Percentage": 0,
      "Amount": 0,
      "UpdateOperation": "Unspecified"
    },
    {
      "DistributionSet": "CC",
      "LineNumber": 2,
      "DistributionCode": "MASTER",
      "Description": "Mastercard",
      "GLAccount": "1023",
      "Discountable": "Yes",
      "Percentage": 0,
      "Amount": 0,
      "UpdateOperation": "Unspecified"
    },
    {
      "DistributionSet": "CC",
      "LineNumber": 3,
      "DistributionCode": "AMEX",
      "Description": "American Express",
      "GLAccount": "1021",
      "Discountable": "Yes",
      "Percentage": 0,
      "Amount": 0,
      "UpdateOperation": "Unspecified"
    }
  ],
  "UpdateOperation": "Unspecified"
}
```

Basically, there is a DistributionSetKey called CC.  And under CC, there are different child elements like VISA, AMEX, MC, etc.  Can I filter by VISA which is the DistributionCode?

This is what I have tried:
http://localhost/AbcWebApi/v1.0/-/ABC/AP/APDistributionSets?$filter=(DistributionSetDetails/DistributionCode eq 'VISA')

And this is the error I'm getting:
"The parent value for a property access of a property 'DistributionCode' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."

Any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of OData are you using? Is this a service you run or a service you're making requests to?

Comment: I am using OData 4.0.  It's a service I'm making requests to.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

DistributionSetDetails is a collection and the filtering must be done on 1 item and not on a whole collection.

To fix this just add "all" or "any" like this to specify what to filter.

```
?$filter=DistributionSetDetails/all(d: d/DistributionCode eq 'VISA')
```